# How i can validate attr in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How I can validate attr in Ruby?

My file airplane.rb

```
class Airplane

include Validatable

attr_reader   :aircraft_type, :weight
attr_accessor :speed, :altitude, :course

def initialize(aircraft_type, options={})
    @aircraft_type  = aircraft_type.to_s 
    @course                 = options[:course]     || random_course  
    @weight         = options[:weight]     || rand(1...1000)
    @speed          = options[:speed]      || rand(1...500)
    @apltitude      = options[:apltitude]    || rand(50...3000)
    @position_x         =   options[:position_x] || rand(1...3000)
  @position_y           = options[:position_y] || rand(1...3000)
  check_course
end 

def position
 @position = [@position_x, @position_y]
end

def check_course
if @course < 1
    @course = 1
    puts "Invalid course. Set min"
elsif @course > 360
    @course = 360
    puts "Invalid course. Set max"
else
    @course = @course
    end
end

def random_course
@course = rand(1..360)
end
```

end

My file validatable.rb where all values ​​must be checked

```
module Validatable

@@validations={}
# I need receive = {presence: [:weight, :length], aircraft_type: [:length]}

def self.validates_presence_of(*attrs)
    @@validations[:presence] = attrs
end

def validate 
    @@validations.each do |v, fields| 
        fields.each {|field_name| self.send("validate_#{v}_of", field_name)}
    end
end

private 

    def validate_presence_of(field_name)
    end
```

end

My file init.rb with airplanes attr

```
airplane1 = Airplane.new("Boeing 74", course: 600, speed: 300, apltitude: 300)
airplane2 = Airplane.new("Boeing 700", course: 250, speed: 300, apltitude: 300)
airplane3 = BigAirplane.new("Boeing 707", weight: 50, speed: 300, apltitude: 400)
```

How I can finish validatable.rb to validate each value in each airplane?

Comment: When you instantiate the object, you are loading it with default values. So they will only be nil if the user specifically changes it to nil later. Please explain that flow better. Also, have you looked at rails activerecord validations? You can include it without the rest of the ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Use ActiveModel::Validations instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Refer:

```
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/
```

and

```
http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html
```

and

```
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ok. But need in my way:))) What need in 
 validate_presence_of
for check for negative numbers

Comment: @Savroff List examples of invalid data and the messages you want to see.

Comment: invalid if

 i.to_s
///
 i < 0